Relevant simulation of a deterministic process needed in the simulation of a stochastic process
Suppose that $g$ is a $d\times d$ deterministic matrix function and that $h$ is a $d$-dimensional deterministic vector function and that these two functions are regular enough for what happens next.
Setting $\sigma_x (t) \equiv g(t) h(t)$ let's consider the $d$-dimensional stochastic process $x$ solution of the following SDE : $$ dx_t = (y(t)\mathbf{1} - \chi(t) x_t) dt + {}^t \sigma_x (t) dW^{\mathbf{Q}}_t$$ with $x_0 = 0$, where $\mathbf{1}$ is the $d$-dimensional vector with all coefficients equal to $1$, where $y(t)$ is a $d\times d$ matrix function defined by : $$y(t) = H(t) \left( \int_0^t {}^t g(s) g(s) \right) H(t).$$ One can show that $y$ satisfies the following ODE : $$y'(t) = H(t) {}^t g(t) g(t) H(t) - \chi (t) y(t) - y(t) \chi(t)$$ with $y(0) = 0$.
Now if we want to simulate $x$ at a time discretization $0 = t_0 < t_1 < \ldots < t_d$ one can tactically take advantage of the fact that $x_{t_{i+1}}$ is, conditionally to $x_{t_i}$, a gaussian vector with computable mean and variance, namely : $$(E)\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\mathbf{E}^{\mathbf{Q}}\left[ x_{t_{i+1}} \left| x_{t_i} \right.\right] = e^{-\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} \chi (u)du} x_{t_i} + \int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} e^{-\int_s^{t_{i+1}} \chi (u)du} y(s) \mathbf{1} ds.$$
and write that $$x_{t_{i+1}} = e^{-\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} \chi (u)du} x_{t_i} + \int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} e^{-\int_s^{t_{i+1}} \chi (u)du} y(s) \mathbf{1} ds + \sqrt{\mathbf{Var}^{\mathbf{Q}}\left[ x_{t_{i+1}} \left| x_{t_i} \right.\right]} Z_i$$ where $\sqrt{\mathbf{Var}^{\mathbf{Q}}\left[ x_{t_{i+1}} \left| x_{t_i} \right.\right]}$ is a square-root of the variance matrix (Cholesky for instance) and $Z_1,\ldots,Z_d$ a sequence of independent and identically distributed standard $d$-dimensional gaussian vectors.
Fine. So we need to treat numerically the integral $$\int_{t_i}^{t_{i+1}} e^{-\int_s^{t_{i+1}} \chi (u)du} y(s) \mathbf{1} ds$$ from equation (E). What is the most sound way (for numerical precision and performance) to do this in general ? And if $g$ and $h$ are piecewise constant on the given time-discretization ?
